# Date From Week Number & Week Day Name

Tags: excel

Is it Possible to get the Date from the given Week Number and the Day Name?

for Example if the below criteria matches then the outcome would the a date

```
   Year: 2019
   Week Number: 45
   Day Name: Friday
   Outcome: 8/11/19
```

How is this possible?

Comment: You need the year, too.

Comment: Yes, you also need year to get exact result.

Comment: Okay, how would I be able to do it to get this year, the outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=DATE(B1,1,1)+(B2-1)*7+MATCH(B3,{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"},0)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B1,1,1)+(B2-1)*7,2)
```

See this picture for the meaning of input cells:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you've three columns

1. Year at **A2**
2. Week Number at **B2**
3. Day Number at **C3** 
   You can use following formula to get exact date

   =DATE(A2, 1, C2-3) - WEEKDAY(DATE(A2, 1, 3)) + B2 * 7

[image]

**Note!** This formula is based on ISO week numbers, with a week starting on Monday

Comment: Thank you :), but how would I get the Date from the only Day Name for Year would be 2019, Week would be 45 and Day Name would be Friday